# How to add class to specific number of increment div's child in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, increment

As I am using a increment in PHP which output the number (1-unlimited) to div class ->

First of all let's see the code:

```
  <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    
    <div class="1-<?php echo ++$i ?>">
<h1 class="text">Demo</h1>
</div>
    
    <?php endwhile;
```

So i want to add a class to h1 or to div (like div class= 1-2 late) if div class is = 1-2 means how to add a class to h1 if increment number is two (2)

I expects

```
<div class="1-1">
    <h1 class="text">Demo</h1>
</div>
<div class="1-2">
    <h1 class="text class-here">Demo</h1>
</div><div class="1-3">
    <h1 class="text">Demo</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you expect as the output as it's not entirely clear (to me anyway).

Comment: sure. check the updated one

Comment: Seems like an XY Problem.  Why bother to add the class to the `h1` tag.  Just make a style declaration like `.1-2 h1 { /* your stylings */ }`.  For the record, I do not recommend using classes that start with numbers.

Comment: that's why i don't want to use number classes

Comment: No answers there ???

Comment: @E - Gyan Can you please check answer accept if useful?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT after OP's clarification

To only output the class if its the second loop you need an if statement

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<?php $i++; // increment i by one ?>
<div class="1-<?php echo $i ?>">
    <h1 class="text <?php echo(($i = 2) ? ' some-class' : '') ?>">Demo</h1>
</div>
```

AGAIN: do not start your classes with a number. Start them with a letter.

ALSO: if you only want to add different styles to the second loop-items h1 you can simply use css for that. Give the wrapping div for all loop items a class like i.e. "article", then do this

```
.article:nth-child(2) h1 {
    /* your styles */
}
```

OLD ANSWER

Not sure if I get your question right but why don't you simply increment $i and then use it:

```
  <?php $i = 0; ?>
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <?php $i++; // increment i by one ?>
    <div class="1-<?php echo $i ?>">
        <h1 class="1-<?php echo $i ?> text">Demo</h1>
    </div>

<?php endwhile;>
```

Also if your wrapping div already has a class, you could simply access the h1 like this

```
.\32 1-2 h1
```

CSS identifiers should not start with a number, this can lead to trouble (which is why I am escaping it above). It's better to add a letter in front of the classname like

```
.wrapper-1-2
```

Comment: i don't want to add increment number to h1 i want to add special class to h1 or div itself

Comment: and can't directly add class to h1 because it will be added to each h1 of each div

Comment: numbers of div is unlimited. so can't use your method

Comment: will try it and ensure the results

Comment: i want to reflect h4 with this code. i means if increment is 1 (means first div) then show h4 else show h5. how this can be ?

Comment: and your code adding some-class to each div

Comment: No answers there ??

Comment: That is a different requirement than what you posted in your question. Next time please try to post a complete and thourough description of what you are trying to achieve. Thgat being said, there are many ways to achieve this. One way to switch between h4 and h5 would be : 
<?php $headertype = $i = 1 ? 'h4' : 'h5'); ?>  
<<?php echo $headertype ?> class="text>Demo</<?php echo $headertype ?>>

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```html
<div class="1-<?= ++$i === 2 ? $i . ' class-here' : $i ?>">
    <h1 class="text">Demo</h1>
</div>
```

If `$i` equals 2 then it will add `$i` as class as well as your extra class. If not, it will only add `$i` as class.